# Uploading PDF to Amazon S3 and display in-browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading PDF's to AmazonS3 manually, using Panic Transmis and via a PHP script/API. 
For some reason, some display in your browser, and some force download. 
I have checked permission and can not seem to see any issues, Can anyone help explain how to make PDF's always display in browser ( unless the user specifies otherwise ).

I don't think it is as browser issue.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to change the Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

```
Content-Type: application/pdf;
Content-Disposition: inline;
```

Using the AWS S3 console, find the file and using the context menu (right click) select Properties then it's under Metadata.

Or change this programmatically: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/create_object

Answer (score 5):

In companion with well's answer, here an example:

```
public function save($bucket, $name, $content, $options = [])
{
    $this->s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $name,
        'Body' => $content,
    ] + $options);
}

$this->bucket->save('my-bucket', 'SofiaLoren.pdf', $content, [
    'ContentType' => 'application/pdf',
    'ContentDisposition' => 'inline',
]);
```